# refreshing the page results in 404 error- Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am building an application with the help of **Angular6** and facing problems in routing. All the **routes** are working when I click on a particular tab but whenever I **refresh** the current page, it is throwing **404** error. I have seen many posts regarding this issue on Stack overflow but failed to overcome from this problem.

Below is my app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {FetchApiComponent} from './fetch-api/fetch-api.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {UserServiceLatest} from './fetch-latest/app.service';
import {UserServiceTop} from './fetch-top/app.service';
import {YoutubePlayerModule} from 'ngx-youtube-player';
import {SidebarComponent} from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import {FetchLatestComponent} from './fetch-latest/fetch-latest.component';
import { FetchTopComponent } from './fetch-top/fetch-top.component'
import {UserService} from './fetch-api/app.service';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { firebaseConfig } from './../environments/firebase.config';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {PushService} from './push.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',

  component: FetchApiComponent
  }, 
{
    path: '/latest',

    component: FetchLatestComponent
  },
{
    path: '/top',

    component: FetchTopComponent
  },
{
path :'*',
component: FetchApiComponent 
}

];

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FetchApiComponent,SidebarComponent, FetchLatestComponent, FetchTopComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    BrowserModule, YoutubePlayerModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,environment.production ?ServiceWorkerModule.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js'):[],ServiceWorkerModule.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    HttpClientModule,environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js') : [], ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [UserService,UserServiceTop,UserServiceLatest,PushService],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can you point me in right direction?

Comment: If you go manually to root path, is loading the FetchApiComponent properly? Is it only happening when refreshing?

Comment: It is only happening when I am refreshing the page. For example: My URL is: `http://localhost:4200/` , there are navigation links on the page, Fetch is one among them, when I clicks on Fetch bar, then it is making the URL as : `http://localhost:4200/fetch` and it is working fine, but when I refreshes this page, then it is throwing me the error.

Comment: I don't understand how is working the first time you access http://localhost:4200/, as it is the same as if you refresh the page... when you refresh, which url is trying to access? are you getting an error in the javascript console for the router?

Comment: Ok I see, that is happening due to your webserver, give me two minutes and I can give you an example in how to solve this

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You will see in your example url, that once you get the 404 error you can't make it work, but if you **include a hash before** the angular-specific url like `/#latest` it will work.

Why stops working when refreshing? your **webserver is intercepting the GET** request from your browser and is trying to go directly to the directory `/latest`, which doesn't exist. It doesn't know that it needs to go to `/bosv2`, find an angular app, and then add the small ending bit to your path which is a not-real directory but a routing for angular. In your local it would work as when you are doing ng serve, webpack webserver is prepared for this, but not the host where you are hosting the app.

By default, angular is using **HTML5 style navigation**, but with your current webserver settings you would need the old angularjs style (with hash#).

From here, you have **two solutions**:

1. Change your webserver configuration
2. Tell Angular to use HashLocationStrategy (perfectly valid solution), you can go old-school with the HashLocationStrategy by providing the `useHash: true` in an object as the second argument of the RouterModule.forRoot in the AppModule.

   @NgModule({
     imports: [
       ...
       RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/latest/
     ],
   ...

I would say going the hash style has a **couple of downsides**, which may not be relevant in your scenario:

1. It doesn't produce the clean and SEO Friendly URLs that are easier for users to understand and remember.
2. You can't take advantage of the server-side rendering.

Hope you find this answer helpful :)

Comment: How to use `useHash:true` with Angular 6?

Comment: it is actually angular6: [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy)

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you if there is any downside of using hash tag in URL or it is completely safe to use?

Comment: Okay..Thank you :)

Comment: @JavierAviles how to change the web server configuration? I've hosted my website on IIS currently and I don't want to use hashing

Comment: you should be able to do it with an .htaccess file

Comment: If you want to configure your webserver and use SEO friendly URLs, check my answer below. IIS configuration is also there.

Comment: Is it possible without using useHash: true ?

Answer (score 35):

To avoid using hashed routes, you must edit your webserver configuration properly, which is the best solution. You just have to configure it so it fallbacks to `index.html`, which is Angular's bootstrap. Although there is no universal configuration for this, here are some:

**Apache**

Add a rewrite rule to `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

**Nginx**

Use `try_files` in your location block

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

**IIS**

Add a rewrite rule to `web.config`

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

**GitHub Pages**

You can't configure it directly, but you can add a 404 page. Copy `index.html` into `404.html` in the same directory or add a symlink: `ln -s index.html 404.html`.

**Firebase hosting**

Add a rewrite rule.

```json
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

Source: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: Worked great! Thank you :) (using Angular 7)

Comment: any idea about how to setup on JBOSS server?

Comment: I am not really familiar with JBOSS, but try this: ```<error-page><location>/index.html</location></error-page>``` It should redirect error pages to Angular endpoint (index.html)

Answer (score 28):

With .htaccess you can try with following way also:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: A real hero! Thanks for this.

Comment: This seems to work, though on refresh am getting new these errors  
 runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
polyfills.fb102f8799c272a4b157.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
scripts.45d295297da9627b2108.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
main.5dc5f9f560e306c1feb5.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: @user3530687 - that is already in the answer - in short, that control assigns to the index.html file, rather than finding some file like passed through.

Comment: Many are forgetting  to add RewriteRule ^ - [L], see the answer completely, dont just copy the last part

Comment: Real life hero!

Answer (score 10):

In app.module.ts

```
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
```

After import add following line to providers.

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

ex:

```
providers: [AuthService, 
            AuthGuard, 
            FlxUiDataTable,
            {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

This will solve your issue. Read [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) here.

Answer (score 9):

Add `.htaccess` file to your `src` folder.

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Load `.htaccess` file in your build directory `dist` by adding it to `assets` in `angular.json`

```
"assets": [
     "src/favicon.ico",
     "src/assets",
     "src/.htaccess"
],
```

Comment: Worked in one shot, Thanks!

Comment: Hello It worked on bigrock server But it Not worked in AWS server
Why it's happened anybody knows??

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting 404 because your are requesting http://localhost/route which doesn't exist on tomcat server. As Angular 2 uses html 5 routing by default rather than using hashes at the end of the URL, refreshing the page looks like a request for a different resource.

When using angular routing on tomcat you need to make sure that your server will map all routes in your app to your main index.html while refreshing the page. There are multiple way to resolve this issue. Whichever one suits you you can go for that.

**1) Put below code in web.xml of your deployment folder :**

```
<error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

**2) You can also try using HashLocationStrategy with # in the URL for routes :**

Try using:

RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })

Instead of:

RouterModule.forRoot(routes)

With HashLocationStrategy your urls gonna be like:

http://localhost/#/route

**3) Tomcat URL Rewrite Valve : Re-write the url's using a server level configuration to redirect to index.html if the resource is not found.**

3.1) Inside META-INF folder create a file context.xml and copy the below context inside it.

```
<? xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
</Context>
```

3.2) Inside WEB-INF, create file rewrite.config(this file contain the rule for URL Rewriting and used by tomcat for URL rewriting). Inside rewrite.config, copy the below content:

RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} !-f

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.html [L]

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Apache 2.4, you can use the FallbackResource directive instead of rewriting, so it will look like:

```
FallbackResource /index.html
```

If you have a different base href (say, /awesomeapp), change it for:

```
<Location /awesomeapp>
    FallbackResource /awesomeapp/index.html
</Location>
```

Comment: yet very simple and working solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cpanel then it is easy to solve this issue.

Go to **Advanced Options**

> Step 1: Go to Error Pages.

> Step 2: Copy your index.html code and paste it in 404.shtml.

> That's it technically all your routes are redirected to index.html file. That's what angular wants :) and everything will work normal.

Here are some reference links

[Namecheap Error Page Config](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/193/29/how-to-add-custom-error-pages)

[Godaddy Error Page config](https://in.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/Getting-Hosting-Account-to-Recognize-My-Custom-404-Page/td-p/19887)

Comment: this is good a a "fallback" option. But in case of 404 it will not load the same page/route, but the default route.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a "good fallback", more like a "last resort", as this has an important failing: Your page/request returns a 404 HTTP response (which cannot be overridden by Angular) - so won't be indexable by Search Engines! @CoenDamen

Answer (score 0):

In my case i did following thing

**Method 1 :**

in your **app.module.ts** import below thing

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and build with

> ng build --base-href /[PROJECT_NAME]/

**method 2 :**

for nginx,

> nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

add follwing line in  location block

```
location /[PROJECT_NAME] {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /[PROJECT_NAME]/index.html;
}
```

> sudo service nginx restart

and build with

> ng build --base-href /[PROJECT_NAME]/

Answer (score 0):

Refetch data on same URL navigation

> imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
>       onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'   })],

Answer (score 0):

Make an `.htaccess` file and add this code; routes will start working:

```
RewriteEngine On
 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```