# ionic as pwa with angular/pwa 404 not found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I have an ionic app that I use as a `pwa`, I have install `@angular/pwa` with `ng add @angular/pwa` then I run `ionic build --prod` and I upload all y www folder on my server but when I refresh a page I got `404 Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.`

Someone knows why ? I don't know which file and folder I should share with you to help so let me know if needed. Thank ou everyone

Comment: can you expand on what is the issue?  the build succeeds and you can go to www on your computer and launch http-server from that www folder and access pwa but after you upload it to your hosting it does not work or?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes the build succeeds, the launch http-server works but when I refresh the page it gives error page instead of refreshing the page... same thing on the real server ...

Comment: so you just press browser refresh and it goes 404?  does this look similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907736/refreshing-the-page-results-in-404-error-angular-6?

Comment: yes it's quiet the same, but they use a trick of angular using # in url and I don't want to use it..

Answer (score 1):

Working well with Ionic `LocationStrategy` provider for `app.module.ts` [as described here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-deeplinker-angular-html5mode-urls-without/74530/2)

Build your Ionic sources with `ionic build --prod`, and serve the generated `www` folder with NGINX.

NGINX `default.conf` configuration example :

```
 server {
    ...
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html?$args;
    }
    ...
```

NGINX's `try_files` directive will do the job with Ionic PWA routing. Page refresh with **F5 will not display 404 anymore :)**

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late for you, but I had the same trouble with my PWA. If you look in your www folder and open your index.html file you will need to make this change.

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="">
```

If the above doesn't work you can try putting a .htaccess file in your project root directory that sends all request back to the index.html page. Just create the file .htaccess and put the below code inside the file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
ErrorDocument 404 https://in-info-web4.informatics.iupui.edu/~username/appName/
```