# Ionic 5: on browser builded app, how to prevent the 404 error on reload

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, url, angular9, ionic5

Here is the deal. I have an ionic app that our client open from a link as if it was another web page. But the problem is that if the client reloads the page on this ionic app, they got a 404 error.

I found out that it came from the URL that is modified by ionic (and angular), that looked like this:

```
http://address/app-directory/www/#/current-page
```

It's the first app we do in Ionic 5, before, we were using Ionic 3, where the URL looked like that:

```
http://address/app-directory/www/index.html#current-page
```

And it worked like a charm.

I tried to find a solution online, and find out these questions:

- [refreshing the page results in 404 error- Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907736/refreshing-the-page-results-in-404-error-angular-6/50910433)
- [Angular deployment - 404 on page Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072185/angular-deployment-404-on-page-refresh/45073371)

But they didn't really help. One suggested solution from the questions would be to change the server configuration, but from my current situation, it would be the solution chose only if I can't do it another way.

If it can help, our app paired Ionic 5 with Angular 9.

Comment: Check in index.html the baseHref so u change it to the needed main path.

Comment: @MostafaHarb well it didn't do anything, sadly

Comment: DId you manage to solve this?

Comment: @leonardofmed yes, but by making a server side solution, so not by doing something someone can reuse will watching this question.

Comment: Thank you, also solved this by using a server side solution, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60295587/7123439