# azure app service angular app 404 error when routes accessed directly

Tags: angular, azure, pm2, azure-appservice

The linux app service is configured with a Node 18 LTS stack and a startup command that's set to:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

The `--spa` tag is supposed to make all routes fallback to index.html which is not the case when accessing an url directly, a 404 error is fired. But when using the root domain, the Angular routing works correctly.

Comment: Please share your `web.config`  file from the deployed azure app `wwwroot` directory.

Comment: There's no `web.config` file, and it seems like by changing the stack to Node 18 LTS and switching the argument `--spa` to the beginning, something happened in the Azure backend, and it worked, in Terraform we can see a new attribute set to index.html : `default_documents = [
      "index.html",
    ]`

Comment: Yes,even you can add `Default documents` in Azure app configuration =>Default document section.

Comment: Can't find that section in my Linux based app service..

Comment: Default document option is available only for Azure Windows App Service.

Comment: we were able to set it for Linux app through terraform, if that's just delusional, do you know how can we set fallback route or "default document" in a Linux based App Service ?

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed the Angular app to Azure Linux App service.

- In your deployed app, `Configuration` => `General Settings` => `Startup Command`, the `start up` command varies based on the type of deployment.
- If you have deployed your App using `Local Git` then the Startup Command has to be

```js
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

Locally , when we run the command `ng build`, dist folder will be created in the project root directory.

***My Configuration***

[image]

> how can we set fallback route or "default document" in a Linux based App Service ?

The option to set  `Default Documents` is available only for  `Windows App Service Plan`.

Thanks @Huw O. Roberts for the Default document script.

For Linux App Service by default `node.js` app treats `hostingstart.html` as the default document. If we want to change the default document, use the below code in your `app.js` or `index.js` file.

```cs
  var options = {
        index: 'index.html'
    };
```

Referenecs taken from [tutorials](https://www.exoduscloudtechnology.co.uk/tutorials/angular-azure-linux)

Comment: I really would have preferred an Azure abstraction as it's a PaaS service, isn't it ? rather than using a hand made express server.. Still, in my case I didn't need all of that just use the default document property in terraform.

Answer (score 0):

When I deployed an Angular application on "**Azure Linux App service**" I experienced the same problem.
I added this attribute to the angular route to ignore this issue.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { useHash: true })
```

You can get more details from this answer [404-error-angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907736/refreshing-the-page-results-in-404-error-angular-6)

We hope that Azure will provide a configuration to **"Azure Linux App service"** like what they did when deploy on **"Azure Static Web Apps"** by add **"staticwebapp.config.json"**

You can find more details here [404-error-azure-static-web-app](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/296)