# How to configure routing on Angular app with DNS pointing to my VPS?

Tags: angular, .htaccess, url, apache2

I have a domain `mydomain.example` which point to my VPS Ubuntu Apache web server. On my VPS I have angular app.

If I go to `http://mydomain.example` it shows the content from `/home` and the browser URL remains `http://mydomain.example`, this is OK and it works. However, if I refresh a page with `reload()` method or refresh button on browser I get an error:

> no page `http://mydomain.example/home`.

How to do this in single page app? Does `.htaccess` help?

Clicking links in my app works. Reload does not work. I think it is because it uses mydomain + angularComponet and not my index.html/angularComponent.

Comment: What do mean by "redirect"?  Do you have a HTTP server configured to issue HTTP redirects?  Or are you using JavaScript redirects within your SPA framework?  Or do you mean redirect to mean that you have DNS pointing to your server?  Exactly what URL is redirecting to what other URL (use `http://` in your URLs please)?  When you say "mydomain" and "myvps" are those separate host names? Why do you want to have "home" in the URL anyway?  The URL for your home page should usually be just the domain name with only a slash (`/') for the path.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller DNS pointing to IP of myvps

Comment: What method are you using to redirect `/` to `/home`?  I don't understand how the URL doesn't change until you hit the refresh.

Comment: This question should not have been closed as "needs details or clarity". The relevant information is already in the question to be able to answer it (hence my "accepted" answer). The additional detail and apparent inconsistencies are really irrelevant in answering this question. The important part is that when they do a hard refresh/reload (ie. an HTTP request) on the non-root/non-cached "Angular" URL, they get a 404. @StephenOstermiller

Comment: I'd vote to re-open if it could be edited in such a way that your answer followed from the rest of the question.  I took a stab at editing, but I have no idea what to do with "redirected URL" in the title for example. As it is currently written, the accepted answer isn't going to useful to anybody else who is able to find this question through search.

Comment: If the question is clearly just about the 404 on refresh, it should be closed as a duplicate of [refreshing the page results in 404 error- Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907736/refreshing-the-page-results-in-404-error-angular-6)

Comment: @MrWhite solved my problem, so you can close this question. Sometimes for us non-english speakers it is not easy to explain a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload/refresh does not work because you are sending a new HTTP request to your (Apache) server and your server does not know how to respond. When you click the links in your application JS/Angular captures the event and routes the request through your Angular front-controller - which all happens client-side (no direct HTTP request to the server, except for those that might be initiated through Angular).

You need to implement a server-side front-controller pattern so that any "unknown" HTTP requests to your server are also routed through the Angular front-controller.

On Apache, you can do something like the following in the root `.htaccess` file (or server config). This uses mod_rewrite.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine on

# Angular front-controller
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

This is a standard front-controller pattern that routes all requests that don't map to files or directories to the file `index.html` (the Angular front-controller) that should then handle the request.

You need to make sure that `.htaccess` overrides are enabled in the server config (`AllowOverride All` needs to be set in the appropriate place eg. `<Directory>` container inside the relevant `<VirtualHost>`, and Apache restarted). You also need to make sure that mod_rewrite is installed/enabled, otherwise this will generate a "500 Internal Server Error" (in which case check your server's error log for details).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what is happening here. It worked like you said. From here I read how to AllowOverride and mod_rewrite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740419/how-to-set-allowoverride-all